# Mapbox not releasing memory after view is removed from navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I have implemented Mapbox in swift and when we go to view-controller which has Mapbox gets around 100mb in the memory and when we pop back the view controller it still have around 40 to 50 mb in the memory. Its not releasing the memory after being removed.

Below is the code I have used

```
    let url = URL(string: AppInfo.appDelegate.versionObj.mapBoxLink)
    mapBoxView = MGLMapView(frame: viewMap.bounds, styleURL: url)
    mapBoxView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    mapBoxView.setCenter(currentLocation, zoomLevel: 15, animated: true)
    mapBoxView.logoView.isHidden = true
    mapBoxView.attributionButton.isHidden = true
    viewMap.addSubview(mapBoxView)
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I am sure that, this question doesn't need any code as its just about a question about the SDK taking much more memory. Still for your concern I have included the code, would appreciate your help if you could.

Comment: hey @ParthDhorda, I think there's a memory leak in the `mapBoxView`. Can you share your definition and if possible view the controller which Mapbox used?

Comment: @ParthDhorda - how will you remove your mapBoxView in viewMap

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - this is how I remove the mapbox

mapBoxView.delegate = nil
            mapBoxView.removeFromSuperview()
            mapBoxView = nil

Comment: @ParthDhorda - are you tried my code, if tired its not works, please update your question based on all code or additional code

Comment: After testing, the answer is keep your map in memory instead of dispose/recreate mapview.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make a weak reference, if you are sure you always set it to nil when you remove the view.

You can try to subclass MGLMapView and see if it is correctly deallocated.
If it is not, that means object is retained by another object. You can try to display the memory graph in Xcode to see who is guilty. It can be an object in the Mapbox framework itself.

```swift
class MyMapView: MGLMapView {
   deinit {
    // BreakPoint Here
   }
}
```

**EDITED**

I have done the test, and map is correctly deinited.

So I guess the unreleased memory is owned by the MapBox framework, and there is nothing you can really do. ( From instruments, there is memory allocated once when the user connects, there is also some GL Texture cache, and other stuffs )

This being said, if your application is a map app, then why don't you simply create a map view and hold it in memory. That's probably the main feature of the application. You just start/stop the user location tracking when view is shown or hidden to save CPU.

Adding and removing the map several times will grow the memory slowly, and at a certain point, the residual memory will be greater than the memory used by a simple map view created once and forever - as you can see on this snapshot. First view installation was taking around 130mb, after some create/dispose map view, it is now 155Mb

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your definition of MGLMapView is weak:

```
weak var mapBoxView: MGLMapView!
```

This prevents the app from strong reference cycles.

Comment: I tried this but its crashing the app as I can assign an object like ==> mapBoxView = MGLMapView(frame: viewMap.bounds, styleURL: url).

Comment: What's the crash log? It's just a type definition.

Comment: Can't assign object to mapBoxView if I define it as weak

Comment: Create a local variable, after creation, setting up and adding to viewMap assign it to mapBoxView weak variable.

Comment: Just tried it and its still same @Makalele

Comment: On which line is the crash and what's the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some code which modifies the properties of that view controller inside a private method which is called inside a closure which takes `self` as weak.

I ran into a similar problem. I had a property which I was modifying inside a private method inside the view controller and I called this method from inside a closure which had weak reference to `self`. The way I fixed this was to remove the private method and put all the code inside this method in the closure.

In my case, I was using Reachability class to check if device is online or offline.

```
reachability.whenUnreachable = { [weak self] _ in
    self?.privateMethod()
}
```

Private method:

```
private func privateMethod() {
    self.someUIElement.someProperty = someValue // need to put this line inside the closure and get rid of this method
}
```

In this case, compiler doesn't throw any errors, but `self` is being retained after telling the compiler that we need only weak reference to `self` inside the closure.

Since you are calling the private method from inside the closure, self should not be retained but it does get retained because inside the private method, self has a strong reference.

I figured this out by logging the `deinit` method and noticed that it wasn't getting called.